# How can I get the number by using 'count' when some nested records were 'nil'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to show the number of users who has the community's uniquecode.

```
@community.uniquecodes.users.count.to_s
```

Why does this return this error?

```
undefined method `users'
```

Please, consider that there is a possibility that uniquecodes still remain but user is deleted!

My association is like this

```
User has_many :communities
     has_many :uniquecodes

Community belongs_to :user
          has_many :uniquecodes

Uniquecode belongs_to :user
           belongs_to :community
```

How can I get the number of users who has the community's uniquecode.

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try

Comment: @CodeGnome sorry I don't get that:( could you please show me the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your relationships are not clear, maybe you need something like a has_many :through association, but the "belongs_to :user" confuses me a little, and what does the uniquecode mean?

Try with

```
User has_one :community
     has_many :uniquecodes
     has_many :communities, :though => :uniquecodes

Community belongs_to :user
          has_many :uniquecodes
          has_many :users, :through => :uniquecodes

Uniquecode belongs_to :user
           belongs_to :community
```

Also, I guess the uniquecode is just a join model, so it shouldn't be there if the user is deleted (the has_many, :through association takes care of that automatically)

that way you can do "community.users"

Comment: Thanks! are you sure about that? If I'm using `through`, won't it be something like `User has_many :uniquecodes, :through => communities?`

Comment: for your definition, Uniquecode would be the join model, check here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association, the join model is the one with both "belongs_to" associations and goes after the :through. MY code is not tested, try it and see if that helps

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
Community has_many :uniquecodes
Uniquecode has_many :users
```

that should make this work:

```
@community.uniquecodes.users.count.to_s
```

Comment: In my case, user has many uniquecodes, how should I define my association? uniquecodes is almost like `Point cards of stores`

Answer (score 1):

#### Using #try for Method Chaining

The Rails [Object#try](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try) method is useful when calling a method on an object that may be nil. Consider the following:

```
1.9.3p362 :001 > @foo = []
 => [] 
1.9.3p362 :002 > @foo.count
 => 0 
1.9.3p362 :003 > @foo = nil
 => nil 
1.9.3p362 :004 > @foo.count
NoMethodError: undefined method `count' for nil:NilClass
1.9.3p362 :005 > @foo.try(:count)
 => nil
```

One problem with method chains like `@community.uniquecodes.users.count.to_s` is that if any method along the chain returns nil, you end up calling the following method on an instance of NilClass. The :try method prevents the NoMethodError exception from being raised in such cases, and is somewhat analogous to calling `@foo.some_method rescue nil`. However, unlike the rescue clause, Object#try is chainable.